# How to close the gap between the dropdownmenu and menuitem

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdownmenu using only css. When I hover over the hamburger-symbol then there is a gap between the hamburger-symbol and the menuitem.
How can I close the gap **using professional code** and only using css?
Flexbox and Grid shouldn't be used.

How can I fix this problem?

Below you can see my current code:

```css
/* ############################## START GLOBAL SETTINGS ############################## */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ############################## END GLOBAL SETTINGS ############################## */


/* ############################## START GENERAL SETTINGS ############################## */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}


/* ############################## END GENERAL SETTINGS ############################## */


/* ############################## START NAVIGATION BAR ############################## */

.header-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.header-nav .container,
.header-nav .row,
.header-nav .col-6 {
  height: 100%;
}

.header-nav ul>li>a:link,
.header-nav ul>li>a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ############################## END NAVIGATION BAR ############################## */


/* ############################## START MOBILE NAVIGATION BAR ############################## */

.col-6 {
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav-button>img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}

.mobile-nav-content>ul>li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-dropdown:hover>.mobile-nav-content {
  display: block;
}


/* ############################## END MOBILE NAVIGATION BAR ############################## */
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="#" alt="">
        </a>

        <div class="mobile-nav-dropdown clearfix">
          <div class="mobile-nav-button">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/2000px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png" alt="Hamburger-Symbol">
          </div>

          <div class="mobile-nav-content clearfix">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">First</a></li>
              <li><a href="leistungen.html">Second</a></li>
              <li><a href="kontakt.html">Third</a></li>
              <li><a href="impressum.html">Fourth</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lazy answer is to tell you to modify `.mobile-nav-content {` to have a `top` value of about 40px instead of the 50 is currently has. Thing is though, this won't actually solve your problem.

See, right now your condition for showing the dropdown is that you're hovering over the burger menu. Even if your dropdown was moved to be touching the burger menu, your hover condition is no longer met as soon as you move the cursor off the burger menu and onto the dropdown.

The ideal way to do this sort of thing is to base the hover event on a common ancestor to both the trigger (in this case: your burger menu) and the drop-down, that way when hovering over either part, the hover condition is met.

```css
.menu-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.drop-holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.burger-menu {
    margin: 10px 10px 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #222;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.dropdown li {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.drop-holder:hover .dropdown {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="drop-holder">
        <div class="burger-menu"></div>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know, why there is a margin, when you hover over the hamburger? https://jsfiddle.net/jq9bxs35/2/

Comment: You've added a 1px border around the `.drop-holder`, the `.dropdown` has no background, and has 50px of `padding-top` overlaid on top of the burger (to make it harder for a user to accidentally close toe dropdown when moving their cursor down). Because the `.dropdown` is `position: absolute; top: 0`, the 1px border has moved `.dropdown` down by 1px